# How to run an Asp.Net based angular application on Node.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio

All the visual studio example for creating angular application is based on asp.net. However I need to deploy the Asp.Net based application on Node.js and I want to use visual studio to debug when developing.

Comment: Maybe this link would help a bit http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode

Comment: Thanks. The page was written in 2011. Does it still apply to current environment? 5 years is really long for such a rapid changing frond-end techs.